# How to use Google Wallet API with JAVA

Tags: java, rest, android-pay

I am trying to use Google Wallet API in a sample project. I read about Google Wallet and found there is two ways to use: Javascript and Android.

But I want to know is there any REST API to call from Java code and implement google Wallet?

Thanks,
Surodip

Answer (score 4):

Go to the google wallet quick start java page [link here](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/web/quickstart-java) and download the sample and configure and build the sample finally run and verify the sample.